# Мне нужно что бы мой "калькулятор" работал без остановки

Tags: python

если в кратце я сделал что-то типа калькулятора, где все параметры выбираются случайно (если быть точнее- оба числа и знаки). Только вот меня бесит постоянно нажимать на кнопку воспроизведения кода. Можно сделать так, чтобы код повторялся постоянно с интервалом в 2 секунды?

---

```
import random
a = float(random.randint(1, 100))
print(f"Первое число:{a}")
b = float(random.randint(1, 100))
print(f"Второе число:{b}")
operation = random.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/', '**'])
print(f"Знак:{operation}")
result = 0
if operation == "+":
    result = (a + b)
elif operation == "-":
    result = (a - b)
elif operation == "*":
    result = (a * b)
elif operation == "/":
    result = (a / b)
elif operation == "**":
    result = (a ** a)
print(f"Результат {result}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random
import time
while True:
    a = float(random.randint(1, 100))
    print(f"Первое число:{a}")
    b = float(random.randint(1, 100))
    print(f"Второе число:{b}")
    operation = random.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/', '**'])
    print(f"Знак:{operation}")
    result = 0
    if operation == "+":
    result = (a + b)
    elif operation == "-":
        result = (a - b)
    elif operation == "*":
        result = (a * b)
    elif operation == "/":
        result = (a / b)
    elif operation == "**":
        result = (a ** a)
    print(f"Результат {result}")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Запихните весь код (кроме импорта) в цикл `while`
***Изменено:*** Извините не заметил приписку в 2 секунды.
Можете попробовать функцию `sleep` из библиотеки `time`:

```
import random
from time import sleep
while True:
    a = float(random.randint(1, 100))
    print(f"Первое число:{a}")
    b = float(random.randint(1, 100))
    print(f"Второе число:{b}")
    operation = random.choice(['+', '-', '*', '/', '**'])
    print(f"Знак:{operation}")
    result = 0
    if operation == "+":
    result = (a + b)
    elif operation == "-":
        result = (a - b)
    elif operation == "*":
        result = (a * b)
    elif operation == "/":
        result = (a / b)
    elif operation == "**":
        result = (a ** a)
    print(f"Результат {result}")
    print('') # Разделение между предыдущим и новым разом (можете не добавлять если не хотите)
    sleep(2)
```